# How to assert the type of an object, in specs2

Tags: scala, types, assertions, specs2

In a specs2 test, how to validate the type of the return value of a function?

Say, the function:

```
trait P
trait C1 extends P
trait C2 extends P

def test(n:Int): P = if(n%2==0) new C1 else new C2
```

Test:

```
"test" should {
   "return C1 when n is even" in {
       val result = test(2)
       // how to assert
       // 'result' should have type of C1?
   }
}
```

I want to know how to assert the type of value `result`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there is a `haveClass` matcher:

```
class FooSpec extends Specification {
  trait P
  class C1 extends P
  class C2 extends P

  def test(n:Int): P = if(n%2==0) new C1 else new C2

  "test" should {
    "return C1 when n is even" in {
      val result = test(2)
      result must haveClass[C1]
    }
  }
}
```